# Laravel Mix & Vue: How do you get multiple CSS outputs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, laravel-mix

I am building 2 bundles because they are separate Vue apps in different sections of the site.  I am choosing in the mix options to have the styles extracted from the VUE file into a CSS file but it is only outputting 1 css file, `vue-styles.css`, and it seems to only have styles from my `app-admin-support.js` app since it's listed below the other one.    Is it possible to have multiple CSS files created?   This is what my mix file looks like :

```
mix .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'dist/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app-admin-support.js', 'dist/js')
    .extract(['vue', 'vuetify'])

mix.options({
  extractVueStyles: true, // Extract .vue component styling to file, rather than inline.
  purifyCss: true // Remove unused CSS selectors.
});
```

Comment: [There are no plans to support this at the moment](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1808). However, it doesn't mean you can't achieve what you want by using the [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) and changing the rule.

Comment: thanks @Ohgodwhy.  I actually came across an article last night on creating multiple mixfiles which seems to meet my needs.  Thanks!!

Comment: @burtonLowel Share that article, please. or post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some days ago, this may help

Simply change your webpack.mix.js into this:

```js
mix .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'dist/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app-admin-support.js', 'dist/js')
    .extract(['vue', 'vuetify'])
    // If you are using vuetifyjs-mix-extension you can do this:
    .vuetify("", { extract: "[name].css" })

mix.options({
  extractVueStyles: true,
  purifyCss: true,
});
```

This is mine, and it can helps:
[image]